# Setting values to an Array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm revising my Java book to make sure i have solid understanding of objects and Java basics in general. I stumbled upon this piece of code from the book i was reading  [Head First: Java 2nd edition (2005)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208)

```
 class Book {   

     String title;
     String author; 

 }

 class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {    

        int x = 0;      

        Book[] myBooks = new Book[3];
        myBooks[0] = new Book();
        myBooks[1] = new Book();
        myBooks[2] = new Book();
        myBooks[0].title = "Example title xx";
        myBooks[1].title = "Example title cc";
        myBooks[2].title = "Example title yy";
        myBooks[0].author = "Example author xx";
        myBooks[1].author = "Example author cc";
        myBooks[2].author = "Example author yy";    

        while (x < 3) {     

            System.out.print(myBooks[x].title);
            System.out.print(", author ");
            System.out.println(myBooks[x].author);
            x = x + 1;  

        }       
    }   
}
```

I don't quite understand the syntax of `myBooks[0].title = "Example title xx"`
I admit i'm not quite experienced with arrays and how they work yet, but isn't it a better practice to loop through the array and set all the object fields with setter methods?

**What i think is the case here**

From my limited understanding, This particular method of assigning values to those fields is related to the scope of those two classes. The same way you'd use names of the static methods instead of first creating object of their respective classes, but with static variables instead.

It seems very trivial, but it's very important for me to understand and grasp the idea. I hope you can clear it up for me.

Comment: `isn't it a better practice to loop through the array and set all the object fields with setter methods?` No, not in this case. You'll need to check the iteration variable (e.g. `i` in `for (int i = .....)`) to know which index you're currently on, to set the correct value. The current way of using a fix index is cleaner here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's rewrite your program without an array:

```
Book myBooks0, myBooks1, myBooks2;
myBooks0 = new Book();
myBooks1 = new Book();
myBooks2 = new Book();
myBooks0.title = "Example title xx";
myBooks1.title = "Example title cc";
myBooks2.title = "Example title yy";
myBooks0.author = "Example author xx";
myBooks1.author = "Example author cc";
myBooks2.author = "Example author yy";
```

If you understand Java variables referencing cusom classes, this should be no mystery at all.

Next, let's go back to your array:

```
Book[] myBooks = new Book[3];
```

It replaces three named variables above with one array variable, so now instead of writing `myBooksX` we write `myBooks[X]`.

That's most of the difference between the two. The advantage of an array is that `X` can be a variable or an integer expression that evaluates to 0, 1, or 2, while with individual variables the number must be hard-coded.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should have specified that my main issue was with the "."  part. But you explained the gist of it to me.

Do you have any resources i could use to learn more about this?

Comment: @Lotix The book you have is a pretty good resource. A good way of deepening your understanding of the subject is to do the exercises after the chapters without looking at the answers, comparing your code to theirs, and understanding the differences.

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   myBooks[0].title = "Example title xx"
   ```

   **will assign the string to the `title` field of the 1st element in the array**
2. Isn't it a better practice to loop through the array and set all the object fields with setter methods?

   Generally speaking yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

when you work with arrays , you should understand the concept.

`Book[] mybooks = new Book[3]`

This means there will be an array in Book type. `Book[0]` means, this is the reference to the real object in memory(as like a remote control to the object).

So when you call the `mybook[0].title` , it means you are calling the title method of `Book[0]` (as like pressing the button title on your Book[0]'s remote control.