# Array project seems to only print out null

Tags: java, arrays, methods, printing, null

The program is supposed to assign random values to the Student objects in the studentArr array.
Right now it is only printing out null values. Ive tried several different print methods.

I'm pretty sure its something wrong with either my method that is supposed to fill out each student object's attributes, or with my print statement.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Lab6Excercise
{
    String[] first={"Rick","Morty","Moriarty","Samus","Promethius","Geiger","Moriarti","Bob","Taco",
            "Asparagus","Shoes","Potato","Dirty","Dan","Spongebob","Space","Nova","Illadin","Orange","Electron"};

    String[] last={"PoopyButthole","Red","Mantis","Toboggan","Oak","Elm","Dumbledore","Potter","Spice","Toothbrush","Argon",
            "Blitz","LazerWolf","Mc-BigMac","King","Queen","Spork","Petrolium","Apple","Trash"};

    //no syntax errors if set to static, but prints out null for everything.
    //problem here or in calling array to print?

    public static Student[] studentArr= new Student[20];
    public Lab6Excercise(){
        initializeArray();
    }

    public void initializeArray(){
        for(int i=0; i>20; i++){
            //this one seems correct but it cant find the symbol method- setStudentID etc. methods
            // online it said to try (Student)studentArr.setStudentID(id())
            //which explicitely casts it

            //seems to work
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328569/setting-values-to-an-array-of-objects
            studentArr[i]= new Student();
            studentArr[i].setStudentID(id());
            studentArr[i].setFirstName(First());
            studentArr[i].setLastName(Last());
            studentArr[i].setGrade(Grades());

            //other way?probably wrong
            //studentArr[i]= new Student(studentArr.id(),
            //studentArr.First(),
            //studentArr.Last(),
            //studentArr.Grades());
        }
    }

    public Student[] getStudentArr(){
        return studentArr;
    }
    //do i even need this?
    //public Lab6Excercise getLab(){
    //    return lab;
    //}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //randomly generate double grade, student id;
        //create 2 arrays, first name, last name. pull randomly for name generation

        //necessary? how do i 
        Lab6Excercise lab= new Lab6Excercise();

        //prints out hash or something
        //System.out.println(lab.studentArr.toString());
        //prints out nulls
        //    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(studentArr));

        for(int i=0; i<studentArr.length; i++){
            System.out.println(studentArr[i]);
        }    

    }
    public int id(){
        int ID=1+(int)(Math.random()*((100-1)+1)); 
        return ID;
    }

    public String First(){
        Random random= new Random();
        int index= random.nextInt(first.length);
        return first[index];
    }

    public String Last(){
        Random random= new Random();
        int index= random.nextInt(last.length);
        return last[index];
    }

    public double Grades(){
        double grade=0+(double)(Math.random()*((4-1)+1));
        return grade;
    }
}
```

and the object class

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Student
{
   private int studentID;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private double grade;

   // no-argument constructor calls other constructor with default values
   public Student() 
   {
      this( 0, "", "", 0.0 ); // call four-argument constructor
   } // end no-argument Student constructor

   // initialize a record
   public Student( int id, String first, String last, double grade )
   {
      setStudentID( id );
      setFirstName( first );
      setLastName( last );
      setGrade( grade );
   } // end four-argument Student constructor

   // set student ID number   
   public void setStudentID( int id )
   {
      studentID = id;
   } // end method setStudentID

   // get student ID number   
   public int getStudentID() 
   { 
      return studentID; 
   } // end method getStudentID

   // set first name   
   public void setFirstName( String first )
   {
      firstName = first;
   } // end method setFirstName

   // get first name   
   public String getFirstName() 
   { 
      return firstName; 
   } // end method getFirstName

   // set last name   
   public void setLastName( String last )
   {
      lastName = last;
   } // end method setLastName

   // get last name   
   public String getLastName() 
   {
      return lastName; 
   } // end method getLastName

   // set grade  
   public void setGrade( double gradeValue )
   {
      grade = gradeValue;
   } // end method setGrade

   // get grade   
   public double getGrade() 
   { 
      return grade; 
   } // end method getGrade

   public static int getRandom(int[] array){
       int rnd= new Random().nextInt(array.length);
       return array[rnd];
    }
   public String toString(){
       return "First name: "+firstName + "Last name: " + lastName+ "ID: "+ studentID+ "Grade: " + grade+"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try reproducing the problem with a simple example? You've posted a lot of code, most of which is probably unrelated to the problem, and that makes it more difficult to identify the issue and so less likely that you'll get a useful response.

Comment: Please select a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize your array, because your `for` loop indexing is wrong.

```
for (int i = 0; i > 20; i++)
```

This says: for `i` starting at `0`, run the following code if `i` is greater than `20`, incrementing the value of `i` by 1 each time. Since `i` starts out already being less than 20, it is never greater than `20`, and the code never runs. Instead, do the following, making your run-condition `i` *less than* `20`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
```

Or, better yet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentArr.length; i++)
```

---

For more details on the syntax of the `for` statement, check out the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! I cant believe i didnt spot that, wouldve saved me several hours and a headache.

Comment: @baconbacon No problem! Your IDE (like Eclipse or IntelliJ) probably has a debug mode, that will allow you to step through your code line-by-line and see exactly what your code is doing while it's running. That can be helpful in spotting errors like these.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple error in your for loop in the initialize array method. The statement: i >20 is the condition under which the loop will execute. But if i starts as 0 it will never be 20 and the loop will never execute. Just change the condition (which is i >20 right now) to i < 20 and it will work. :)